# Finding a Power Series Solution for $y''-y'+xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series, recursion

I'm solving the problem as part of a homework in my second applied analysis course, and I'm having a hard time solving the recurrence. I got

$$
     \begin{cases}
          \begin{align}
               a_1-2a_2&=0\\
               (n+3)(n+2)a_{n+3}-(n+2)a_{n+2}+a_{n}&=0
          \end{align}
     \end{cases}
$$

From which I got

$$
     \begin{align}
          a_{3}=-\frac{1}{3!}a_{0}+\frac{1}{3!}a_{1}\\
          a_{4}=-\frac{1}{4!}a_{0}-\frac{1}{4!}a_{1}\\
          a_{5}=-\frac{1}{5!}a_{0}-\frac{4}{5!}a_{1}\\
          a_{6}=\frac{3}{6!}a_{0}-\frac{8}{6!}a_{1}\\
          a_{7}=\frac{8}{7!}a_{0}-\frac{3}{7!}a_{1}\\
          a_{8}=\frac{14}{8!}a_{0}+\frac{2}{8!}a_{1}\\
     \end{align}
$$.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: See the solution of a question similar to this one in the following link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255984/verify-that-the-equation-yy-xy-0-has-a-three-term-recursion-formula-and-f

Comment: @nmasanta Ah, I see. They use another method since the recurrence is too difficult. I'll leave it as it. Thanks!

Comment: The exact solution involves (linear combinations of) Airy functions: $e^{x/2}F(1/4-x)$ where $F$ is Ai or Bi.

Answer (score 0):

$$y(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5+a_6x^6+a_7x^7+a_8x^8+...$$.
$$y(x)=a_0[1-\frac{1}{3!}x^3-\frac{1}{4}x^4-\frac{1}{5!}x^5+\frac{3}{6!}x^6+\frac{8}{17}x^7+\frac{4}{8!}x^8+...]+a_1[x-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\frac{1}{4!}x^4-\frac{5}{5!}x^5-\frac{8}{6!}x^6-\frac{3}{7!}x^7+\frac{2}{8!}x^8+,,,]$$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. What you wrote is what I have so far; however, I was looking for an exact solution. As Parcly Taxel pointed out, though, the exact solution is beyond the scope of the class I'm taking so I'll just leave the answer as is.

Comment: The exact solution is in terms of exponential and Airy function with shifted argument. It is tedious one.